# Get WordPress logged in username from root domain when WP is installed in a subfolder

Tags: login, cookies, domain, session

Here is my URL structure:

```
http://www.example.com/homepage.php
http://www.example.com/wordpress/
```

Wordpress is installed in a subfolder but I need to get the cookie in homepage.php to check if the user is logged on.

Until now I used a plugin called "Root Cookie" but a couple of days ago it suddenly stopped working after upgrading WordPress to the latest version. I get a fatal error and can't log in until I remove the plugin. This plugin has not been updated for over 8 years so I am looking for an alternative solution, preferably without using any plugin.

> There has been a critical error on your website. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions.

This is the error I was getting with Root Cookie plugin. I never received any email in my inbox, I have also checked the error logs but I didn't find anything.

---

Edit: I have tried to get the current logged in user by including wp-load.php, but it returns empty username and user_id = 0

```
require_once("wordpress/wp-config.php");
require_once("wordpress/wp-load.php");
require_once("wordpress/wp-includes/pluggable.php");
require_once("wordpress/wp-blog-header.php");
require_once("wordpress/wp-includes/user.php");
echo $current_user->user_login;
echo $current_user->ID;
echo $current_user->user_level;
print_r( wp_get_current_user() );
```

> WP_User Object ( [data] => stdClass Object ( ) [ID] => 0 [caps] =>
>   Array ( ) [cap_key] => [roles] => Array ( ) [allcaps] => Array ( )
>   [filter] => [site_id:WP_User:private] => 0 )

I tested with all plugins disabled and with default theme

Comment: Can you debug why it's not working? Does WordPress no longer accept cookies from outside its path? (I haven't heard about that, but I could believe it.) Or does WordPress no longer set the cookies with a root path?

Comment: Depending on what the issue is, you could possibly do this without a plugin by setting COOKIEPATH in wp-config.php. But I assume the existing plugin constructs that path correctly for you. It would better to just fix the plugin if you can.

Comment: I have tried adding COOKIEPATH and COOKIE_DOMAIN to my wordpress config, but it didn't fix the issue :( If I look at the cookie with EditThisCookie extension, I can see the cookie is created with the subfolder path. So I can't get the cookie from the root. I have also tried just getting the logged in user by including wp-load.php but it didn't work. Returns no username and user_id = 0